# Why the CNN is executing more than a training size

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

**why is when len(trainData) = 75 The execution Verbose showing a number greater than 75 ?**

My Model Execution Script

```
batch_size=64
h5_path = "EPOC_1_Feb_25_model.h5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(h5_path, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

history = model.fit_generator(
    data_gen(train2, id_label_map, batch_size, augment=True),
    validation_data=data_gen(val, id_label_map, batch_size),
    epochs=1, verbose=1,
    callbacks=[checkpoint],
    steps_per_epoch=len(train) // batch_size,
    validation_steps=len(val) // batch_size)
model.load_weights(h5_path)
```

---

The Execution Verbose

> Epoch 1/1
>
> 7658/9409 [=======================>......]

given `len(train2) = 75` Why is this showing ***7658/9409*** ?

---

My Data Generator is

```
def data_gen(list_files, id_label_map, batch_size, augment=False):
    seq = get_seq()
    while True:
        shuffle(list_files)
        for batch in chunker(list_files, batch_size):
            X = [cv2.imread(x) for x in batch ] 
            Y = [id_label_map.get(x) for x in batch]#[id_label_map[get_id_from_file_path(x)] for x in batch]
            if augment:
                X = seq.augment_images(X)
            X = [preprocess_input(x) for x in X]
                
            yield np.array(X), np.array(Y)
```

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `steps_per_epoch = len(train) //batch_size` instead of `steps_per_epoch = len(train2) //batch_size`
Because of this you are getting more numbers in data I guess

Comment: You found the Bug in my Code.. 
I just wanted to test the Train Plot accuracy pipeline, and I took a very small fraction of training data as train2. But forgot to match the Steps per epoch . Wondered WHy for looong time. Honestly and Shamelessly.  :-( .. Thanks a LOT

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from your data augmentation. Try setting:

```
augment=False
```

In your `data_gen` call to test it.